# Why my system is detecting only system environment variable path?

Tags: environment-variables

I don't know why my system is only detecting environment variable of system and not user.

For instance, when I put "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin" as first environment variable in user environment variable , I was not able to run "javac" command.
But when I pasted it to system variable it started working.

I know about the dependency issues if I would have placed the path in user variable at the end so I put it at the beginning but still it didn't work..

I searched but found no real solution except dependency issue if I put it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the CMD?
Maybe you have to logoff & logon to refresh the user variables.
It least on my Windows 7 I have the same behavior, new user variable is not available.

Comment: yes I did restarted.But only after pasting it in system variable it gets detected..

Comment: maybe a log off and logon to windows fixes this problem